# New to c++11 features, proper use of shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

So my understanding is that a shared_ptr automatically deallocates from memory when the last remaining owner of the object is destroyed or reassigned, (Seems too good to be true?) and it's useful when many instances may be sharing the same object. Correct?

So in my case, I'm making a 2d tiled world, so I'm drawing many of the same texture to the screen.

I have

```
std::map<int, shared_ptr<Tile>> Tiledb;
```

to store all the tiles. The idea is to only load the texture in once and then i can render it as many times as I want. Then once the game ends I call

```
Tiledb.clear();
```

And this frees all the memory automatically? I'm so conditioned to regular pointers that this just seems magical, and quite frankly, too easy. Am I wrong in thinking this is how it works? Is there any downside to using shared_ptrs? I'm just amazed that this exists haha.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: shared_ptrs are indeed a magical gift from the c++ gods (and the old boost gods). I have large C++ code bases with almost no news and deletes

Comment: My question would be, if you need a `map` of `shared_ptr`'s at all instead of just using a `map` of `Tile`' s or `unique_ptr`s, but aside from that, yes `shared_ptr`'s do exactly what you want. The downside is a small performance penalty whenever you are copying the pointer compared to raw pointers and there is the possibility of cycles (for which there exists `std::weak_ptr`).

Comment: As a rule of thumb: If you don't need polymorphic behavior, you should try to avoid containers of owning pointers altogether.

Comment: Prefer `std::map<int, Tile>` whenever possible.

Comment: Well the idea is in order to load the map I will be reading pixel data from a bmp, where the RGB of each pixel corresponds to a key for a tile in the map. Not sure how to accomplish this otherwise since I'd still like the color in the bmp to be representative of the color of the tile.

Comment: What's the reasoning for not using pointers in containers?

Comment: @picklechips Wrong question: Whats the reason to use pointers in the first place? Always prefer automatic storage duration if feasable.

Comment: Note that you do not need to type `Tiledb.clear()` in this situation. The map's memory gets cleared automatically when it gets destroyed.

Comment: @picklechips What's the reasoning for not using pointers to pointers in containers?

Comment: Next annoying question: Why a `map<int, Tile>`? Why not a `vector<Tile>` and take advantage of the performance boost you get from nice, contiguous data with a dead predictable access pattern? Computers are really, really good at doing stuff in a straight line.

Comment: Also: shared_ptr is not magical, you could write most of it yourself in previous C++ versions, and many programs had their own versions of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ...it's useful when many instances may be sharing the same object. Correct?

Not exactly. It is useful when many instances may be **owning** the same object. Sharing is not enough to justify using a `std::shared_ptr` as there is certainly some overhead to using it.

When you create dynamic resources you need to think about **ownership** ie. *who is responsible for deleting it*? The object that should be responsible for deleting the resource should manage the resource using some kind of *smart pointer* (or a *container*).

If only one object is responsible for deciding when the resource must be deleted then use a `std::unique_ptr`. If other objects/functions need to *share* access to the resource but will never be responsible for deleting it, then pass them a *reference* or a *raw pointer* to the resource.

The time to use a `std::shared_ptr` is when you can not know which of the objects that are *sharing* the resource will be the one that needs to delete it. In that case each object should hold *ownership* of the resource by holding a `std::shared_ptr`.

And even when several objects share *ownership* through a `std::shared_ptr` they should still only pass a *reference* or a *raw pointer* to objects/functions that do not need *ownership* rights.

Another problem with passing `std::stared_ptr` round willy-nilly (where they are not needed) is that they can suffer from the *Java memory leak* problem. That is when objects never die because some reference to them remains in a *forgotten* part of the software. They can gradually accumulate and eat away your memory.

Typically you should prefer keeping your resources in a *container* like a `std::vector` or a `std::map`:

```
std::map<int, Tile> Tiledb;
```

The *container* manages the destruction of the `Tile` so no need for a *smart pointer*.

If, however, you were using *polymorphic* `Tile` objects then you would need to store them using a *pointer*. For this prefer to use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
// When the Tiles are no longer needed after the map is destroyed
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Tile>> Tiledb;
```

If other objects need to keep accessing the `Tile` objects *after* the *map* is destroyed then a `std::shared_ptr` may be appropriate:

```
// only when Tiles need to keep living after the map is destroyed.
std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Tile>> Tiledb;
```

Comment: You mention passing a reference or raw pointer when ownership is not needed. What about `std::weak_ptr` which can also safely check if the pointer has been deleted?

Comment: @JamesAdkison A `weak_ptr` can only safely check *by itself becoming an owner*.  It is an "option" to become strong.  You can stay strong for a short period, but in that period you are extending the lifetime of the object.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, of course but that's better than invalidating a reference or raw pointer (which may be possible depending on the use case). To be clear, I'm not saying `std::weak_ptr` should always be used, just that it seems like it should be presented as an option along with references and raw pointers.

Comment: @JamesAdkison I don't view a *weak_ptr* as an alternative to *raw pointers* at all. Their use is partly a *sub case* of *shared ownership* and partly a special circumstance in its own right. I just didn't want to over-complicate the issue.

Comment: @james shared ptr in my experience leads to muddy ownership and more problems than it solves.  Make ownership clear, use values not references/pointers, keep state immutable, etc: all better approaches than exposing shared ptrs.  Weak ptr usually muddies things further.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely.
Class types have constructors and destructors.
They are called implicitly during instantiation and at the end of the variable's lifetime.

This concept is known as [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii), and its what smart pointers leverage for automatic memory management.

It depends on your use case, but you may consider using unique pointers as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

struct Foo{

  Foo(){
    std::cout << "construct\n";
  }

  ~Foo(){
    std::cout << "destruct\n";
  }
};

int main(){
  std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> m;

  //prints construct 3 times
  m.emplace(1,std::make_unique<Foo>());
  m.emplace(2,std::make_unique<Foo>());
  m.emplace(3,std::make_unique<Foo>());

  //prints destruct 3 times
  m.clear();
}
```