# Proper use of shared_ptr stored in class member vector

Tags: c++, vector, std, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I have some code like this:

```
// MyObj.h
class MyObj
{
    private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyObj> > _children;
    public:
        void addChild(std::shared_ptr<MyObj> child);
};

// MyObj.cpp
void MyObj::addChild(std::shared_ptr<MyObj> child)
{
    MyObj::_children.push_back(child);
}
```

This seems to work fine for me, but I'm wondering if I'm using the right kind of smart pointer. These child objects are declared dynamically and passed to be stored here, and there's a `getChildren` function that returns the vector that contains them. They should only live here, and should die when the parent object dies.

Based on [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801184/new-to-c11-features-proper-use-of-shared-ptr), I'm wondering if I shouldn't be using [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead. I tried that initially, and was getting errors, even when trying to change ownership by calling `std::move` like this:

```
void myObj::addChild(std::unique_ptr<MyObj> child)
{
    MyObj::_children.push_back(std::move(child));
}
```

Is it okay for me to use `std::shared_ptr` like I've shown, or should I use `std::unique_ptr`, and what would that look like? Do I need to use `std::move` when calling the `addChild` function as well?

Comment: The answer to this question completely depends on your use case. Do you want shared ownership of `child` or not? In other words, do you want to allow objects to have simultaneous ownership of `child`?

Comment: It is all about ownership expression.  If only one person will ever own the pointer then a `unique_ptr` is more appropriate.  If ownership is shard then a `shared_ptr` is appropriate.

Comment: *"was getting errors"*. Which ones ? (If you want help on that)...

Comment: @Jarod42 I figured I'd get an ask for that - I would've shared them but I didn't save the output and since I moved to a `shared_ptr` I'm not getting the same. If I switch it back I can repost the errors if I start getting them again.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I guess what I am confused over is what constitutes ownership. If I'm allowing client code to call a `getChildren` function that returns the value of the `_children` vector, that client still doesn't own my class's children, right?

Comment: Ask yourself: when `MyObj` is destroyed should the children it contains also be destroyed?  If not why not, you have called them children which implies a parent-child relationship and this normally implies ownership.  If you are confused about ownership stop coding and get it clear in your mind 1st.

Comment: It would be better to use `emplace_back` than `push_back`, IIRC, as the latter will cause an unnecessary move. To address your question, you will need to use `std::move()` when calling `addChild()` if the argument is not a temporary. We'd need to see the code calling `addChild()` to tell you for sure. See [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/299f1d0e0f8848c3).

Comment: @JustinK In general, the owner(s) of a thing can be seen as "who's in charge of deciding when to delete this thing". If your `child` object's lifetime depends on more than one object, you have shared ownership. If you aren't sure, consider using `shared_ptr` as it's slightly easier to use at the cost of performance.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux @RichardCritten thanks for posing it like that. The answer to your question(s) is yes, I would expect the children to be deleted when the parent is deleted. I do need the ability for client code to get the value of the `_children` vector and recurse through it, but anytime the parent is deleted, the children must go also. So I'm thinking this should be modified to use `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @cdhowie thank you, I'm guessing that omitting `std::move` when I was passing the `unique_ptr`s was the source of my problem. I'll modify my code; if it works I'll answer this question myself. If I run into further problems I'll edit my question and ask for further assistance. Thank you all for your insight.

Comment: @JustinK So how did you solve that? Did you use unqiue_ptr or shared_ptr for _children? What did your getChildren function return?